# Mysql - change data for all users

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for solution to change data for all user in one column. Now I have column "user_personal_image" and there are encoded array with info:

```
{"original":"photo_uploads\/original_2O52S6nhQrCSv3RZStlbY.jpg","thumb_index":"photo_uploads\/thumb_index_2O52S6nhQrCSv3RZStlbY.jpg"}
```

and I need to change `thumb_index` to `thumb` for all users using only SQL query in client, is this even possible?

P.S. all data is different in all columns, there is only same keys "original" and "thumb_index"

Comment: "thumb_index" to thumb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to change both the array key and the path This should do it:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET user_personal_image = REPLACE(user_personal_image, 'thumb_index', 'thumb')
```

This would change the string to:

```
{"original":"photo_uploads/original_2O52S6nhQrCSv3RZStlbY.jpg","thumb":"photo_uploads/thumb_2O52S6nhQrCSv3RZStlbY.jpg"}
```

If you only want to change the array key use:

```
REPLACE(user_personal_image, '"thumb_index"', '"thumb"')
```

or if it is the path use:

```
REPLACE(user_personal_image, '/thumb_index', '/thumb')
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45352f/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
UPDATE yourTable
       SET user_personal_image = REPLACE(user_personal_image, 'thumb_index', 'thumb')
```